# run with difference jar?

Tags: java, jar, dependencies

I am from .net world. I remember .net will immediately complain if you build with one dll but supply a different dll at run time.

I am now adding some hadoop reference to my project and find the following article.

http://answers.mapr.com/questions/364/maven-repository-for-mapr-jar-files

I just don't understand how this happens.

Java can build with one jar but run with a different jar?

Thanks

Comment: Lookup [binary compatibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html)

Comment: I will probably wrong. .net will complain only if the version is not correct, I remember, so dll is what it is for. To dynamically link libraries. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes.  this is often the case with APIs (you compile the API, but at runtime you may run with a newer version of the API which may be included with the implementation).  everything will work out fine as long as the classes/method prototypes referenced in your compiled code are unchanged from the jar you compiled against.

For a specific definition of compatibility, see [binary compatibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html) (thanks to @MiserableVariable for the link).

Comment: @MiserableVariable - is there some compatible change?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand the question.

Comment: @MiserableVariable - you said "define unchanged".  i took that to mean that you were implying that some form of change is acceptable while some isn't (aka, there is some form of "compatible change").

Comment: Oh ok :) Yes, there are many compatible changes, e.g. it is ok for a class in the the production jar to have additional methods. You already quoted my reference to binary compatibility, you can read all the gory details there.

Comment: @MiserableVariable - yes, i realize.  i was a bit brief in my answer, but i meant that the jar has the same classes, and any reference methods were the same.  i'm aware that lots of other stuff can change without it causing a problem.